# Map Values from one dataframe to another based two criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe (df) that contains home field advantage values for various conferences. The first columns represents the home teams and the remaining column headers represent the away teams. I would like to create a new column, `df1['hfa']` in the second dataframe (df1) that shows the home field advantage located in df for the respective matchups listed in df1. Below are  images of the two dataframes. In excel I can achieve this with a two way lookup via Index Match. I would like to map the values from df to df1 for df1['hfa'] so that that they read: 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, etc. Thank you in advance!

I have the following code:

```
df1['hfa'] = df1['Home Team'].map(df.set_index('Home Team')[])
```

I am unsure what to use in the final argument to match the Away Team from df1 to the same column header.

[image: df]

[image: df1]

Comment: Can you show us what `df` looks like, and also what you have tried so far? Have you looked at any of the pandas documentation? I think you'll get more responses if you show that you have made a good faith effort

Comment: Hi derek - Thank you for responding. My apologies for leaving off ```df```. I have gone through the pandas literature but I am a little stumped.  I think I need to use the map function but I am unsure how to use it for multiple criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I undesrstand, this is what I have.  See if this is what you looking for.  Given Data:

[image]

```
(
    df.melt(id_vars=['Home Team'],
            value_vars=['North','East','South','West'],
            var_name='Away Team',
            value_name='hfa')
)
```

[image]